# define ManyToMany relationship via. same column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities with a logical ManyToMany relation between them.

The problem is that I can't have a relation-table, and I know the actual relation because they both have a shared column where if they have the same value they are logically connected.

For example, say I have a `Car` and a `Person`, and they both have a `location`. If both locations are equal then I know they're connected logically.

Is there a way to implement this via `@ManyToMany` or similar JPA/Hibernate annotations?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you've tried and why it doesn't work? Please give an example of a service or DAO that has the results you are looking for.

Comment: That's not ManyToMany. That is a Location entity with OneToMany on both Car and Person. ManyToMany means a Car could be associated with any Person but in this case a Car can only be associated with Persons in the same Location.